# i have a bug in the recycler view while deleting item's

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

items are getting deleted"i have no problem with that"

but the problem is check animation
when item get's deleted the check animation of items below the deleted item is getting unchecked (if its checked)
is this because of the position of item getting miss organized 
[image]
idk what happening

I am new to java
**this is my removeitem func**

```
 public void removeAt(int position) {
    dbhelper.deletecoloumn(listTask.get(position).getID());
    dbhelper.deleteallitem(listTask.get(position).getID());
    listTask.remove(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

**checkanim func**

```
  private void Check(TaskHolder holder,int position){
    if (listTask.get(position).getComplete().equals("0")){
        Log.d(TAG, "Check: equals 0");
        holder.uncheckeditem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.checked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.textViewName.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        holder.textViewName.setPaintFlags(holder. textViewName.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
    }else if (listTask.get(position).getComplete().equals("1")){
        holder.uncheckeditem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d(TAG, "Check: equals 1");
        holder.checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.textViewName.setPaintFlags( holder.textViewName.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        holder.textViewName.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_grey));
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());`. It's enough to call `notifyItemRemoved(position);` since you're deleting a single item.

Comment: ok..please stick with me

Comment: thanks a lot man it worked ..

Comment: you should remove it from your list before you update the notifyItemRemoved. list.remove(position); then notifyItemRemoved(position); thats how i handled it.

Comment: when I delete the last item I am getting 
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 6`
its showing the on the check(position)

Comment: You have multiple `dbhelper` calls inside `removeAt()`. Put a breakpoint there and check which line produces the error.

Comment: the error points me on the check()
am I doing anything wrong in passing position to fuc

`Check(holder,holder.getAdapterPosition());`
this is how I pass the position

Comment: Do you call check() from removeAt()?

Comment: yes

I solved it thanks brother once again

while checking the bug I forgot to remove check()